# Starting Android project with PhoneGap Error

Tags: android, cordova

```
   [error] An error occured during creation of android sub-project. The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I faced this error while I was trying to build my first phonegap android project. When I type this command "phonegap run android " on cmd it shows this error.

Any Help please !

Comment: npm install -g phonegap
phonegap create my-app
$ cd my-app
$ phonegap run android

@Gianmarco ... here the 4 commands used to install and create the android app with phonegap . the problem appear after the 4th one

Comment: Try appending -V at the cmd's end...you can get more information

Comment: be more specific please

Comment: thanks all .. the problem solved by downloading the (www) directory and replace it with the one included with the phonegap directory