# phonegap error occurred while using cordova platform and android

Tags: android, cordova

[Error: An error occured during creation of android sub-project. The system cann
ot find the path specified. Does this mean android SDK path or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution for this problem.

[Starting Android project with PhoneGap Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18613232/starting-android-project-with-phonegap-error)

Else,

Extract the cordova.zip files and replace the android/www folder with your project folder and compile it.